# Cannot add object(s) in an arrayList of object using selectManyCheckbox

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I would like to add one or more object from a list of object into an other empty list. I am sure the first list is already initialized as I am able to print it in the p:selectManyCheckbox.

I think it does not copy the object Comite into the list but just the string as I get the error : java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.primasatis.jsf.model.Comite

Thus how can I copy it into the list ?

```js
public class Comite {
 private int idComite;
 private int idPerimetre;
 private String comite;

 public Comite(int idComite, int idPerimetre, String comite) {
  super();
  this.idComite = idComite;
  this.idPerimetre = idPerimetre;
  this.comite = comite;
 }
}

public static boolean addUserComiteRelation(int idUser, List<Comite> comites) {
  System.out.println(comites.size()); // print the good number
  for(int i=0; i<comites.size();i++) {
     System.out.println(comites.get(i).comite); //error here
   }

 }
```

```html
<h:form>
<p:outputLabel for="Comites" value="Comités" />
<p:selectManyCheckbox id="Comites" value="#{utilisateur.comites}"
       required="true"
       requiredMessage="L'utilisateur doit appartenir à au moins un comité">
<f:selectItems value="#{sessionScope.utilisateur.comites}" />
</p:selectManyCheckbox>
<h:message for="Comites"></h:message>
</h:form>
```

really quick view of my class `utilisateur` (@Named and @SessionScoped)

```js
        public class Utilisateur implements Serializable {
     private Perimetre perimetreUtilisateur = null;
     private List<Comite> comites = null;
     

      @PostConstruct
      private void init() {
       perimetreUtilisateur = new Perimetre();
       comites = new ArrayList<>();
      }
    }
```

Comment: You need an @FacesConverter to convert into your objects.  https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaus.html

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to use `p:selectManyCheckbox` is to provide a `List` of `javax.faces.model.SelectItem` objects.

If you want to use your own Pojos as options in `p:selectManyCheckbox`, then you would have to write a Converter ( `javax.faces.convert.FacesConverter` ).

For Example, your converter would look like :

In My `ManagedBean`(Example: `ComiteManagedBean`) class I would keep all `Comite` instances in a `MAP`(Example: `comiteMap`) with `Comite.idComite` as Key.

```
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.convert.Converter;
import javax.faces.convert.FacesConverter;


@FacesConverter("comiteConverter")
public class ComiteConverter implements Converter {

    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, String value) {
        if(value != null && value.trim().length() > 0) {
            try {
                Comite comite = (ComiteManagedBean) fc.getExternalContext().getApplicationMap().get("ComiteManagedBean");
                return service.getComiteMap().get(Integer.parseInt(value));
            } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
                throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Conversion Error", "Not a valid theme."));
            }
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public String getAsString(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, Object object) {
        if(object != null) {
            return ((Comite) object).getComite();
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! And for `converter="comiteConverter"`, do I have to put it in every `f:selectItems` or should add it in the `p:selectManyCheckbox` ?

Comment: There is no `converter` attribute on `f:selectItems`. It should be used on `p:selectManyCheckbox`

Comment: Oh okay because I have a java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.faces.component._SelectItemsUtil.matchValue(_SelectItemsUtil.java:63) when in `p:selectManyCheckbox `

Comment: Well I found that the string "comite1" and "comite1" are different `System.out.println(comite.getComite() +" " +value);
                 if(comite.getComite()==value) return ...;` and it never does the return whereas it print `comite1 comite1`

Comment: So I tried `if(value != null && value.trim().length() > 0) {
   return new Comite(0, 0, value);
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }`

But it tells me that : `Comités: Validation error: the value is not valide`